# Growing *Sarracenia* in a pond in the Southern Plains

Tags: carnivorous-plants, pond

We have moved to Wichita Falls, Texas. This is Hardiness Zone 7b. We're at the southern end of the Southern Plains, near the Oklahoma border - 2hrs from Oklahoma City, Lubbock, and Fort Worth.

The garden has a pond and a reasonable amount of shade. Can I grow *Sarracenia* in these conditions? I'm thinking it should be possible to grow it as a marginal in a pot that is on a pond shelf (ie. base is submerged), but raised up so that the soil (or coarse sand) surface is an inch or two above the pond surface.  Is that possible? Has anyone tried something like this?

I was thinking of *Sarracenia alata* because of the size (18-24in) and I have seen it growing in the wild in East Texas (shaded bottom-land forest/swamp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen these plants growing wild in USDA zone 4.  It should be possible to duplicate the conditions:

- full sun
- constant access to water but not in the water
- sited at the edge of a hummock of grasses over compacted dead plant material

I would use dried sphagnum moss if you can find it at florists or craft stores. Failing that shredded coconut husk or even wading into the local bog for a quick sample.

Never underestimate the positive effects of local microflora and microfauna on the growth of these plants.  I have no reference but suspect that a dash of the local swamp in your planting medium will be of immense help.

Comment: I've seen the recommendation of full sun elsewhere, yes when I saw S. alata in the wild, it was pretty much full shade - wooded and in the seep from an earth dam. So I was more concerned about too much sun, but perhaps I'm okay...

Answer (score 4):

Yes that should be possible. But read up on the details below.

- [How to grow Sarracenia](http://www.sarracenia.com/faq/faq5552.html). From the Carnivorous Plant FAQ. Good link. [The whole FAQ](http://www.sarracenia.com/faq/faq3000.html) is also helpful.

Above says "zero-nutrient, acid medium". So I assume that means zero nitrates? If you have algae in  your pond then you probably have too many nitrates they are feeding on.

Comment: Thanks. No visible algae. I did some tests a few weeks back and pH was 7 (I understand this is okay for Sarracenia - definitely no more) and both nitrates and ammonia were near zero (lowest or second lowest rungs on the color scales - definitely well below the 'needs treatment' levels).